# Read Hadoop SequenceFile: weird hex number stream

Tags: hadoop, sequencefile

I am trying to convert a piece of Hadoop SequenceFile into plain text with the following code:

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    Path path = new Path( inputPath );
    SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(FileSystem.get(config), path, config);
    WritableComparable key = (WritableComparable) reader.getKeyClass().newInstance();
    Writable value = (Writable) reader.getValueClass().newInstance();

    File output = new File(outputPath);
    if(!output.exists()) output.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "utf-8"));

    int count = 0;

    try {
        while(reader.next(key,value) && count < 1000)
        {
            bw.write("Key::: " + key);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Value::: " + value);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.newLine();
            count++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    reader.close();
    bw.close();
```

The keys can be properly converted. However, the values are converted into weired HEX number stream. A sample is:

```
Value::: 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 e5 bd f9 7b 13 47 d6 28 fc 73 e6 79 e6 7f e8 28 17 6c 5f bc 68 5f 6c e4 5c 96 64 26 33 c9 24 37 cb bc ef 3b 0c 9f 9f 56 77 cb ee 58 96 34 5a 20 8e e3 3f 46 56 c2 10 30 c4 8b e4 4d 5e b1 6c 4b f2 22 59 b2 65 63 48 08 04 42 12 c2 9e 00 21 cb f3 9d 53 d5 2d b5 64 4b 16 33
```

The real stream is much longer than this. What I know is that the keys are stored as `Hadoop Text` format and the values are stored as `Hadoop BytesWritable`. And the values might be in Chinese, but I am not sure about this.

Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: For what it's worth, have you actually tried `hadoop fs -text <src>`? If the `Writable`s have `toString()` implemented, it should print sensible output...

Comment: @TC1 Yes I tried. It just output exactly the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, somehow didn't see the note that values are `BytesWritable`. It makes sense that they are output the way they are -- `BytesWritable` is just what it says it is -- an array of bytes, think `byte[]`. If you want to output them as text (and you say they "might" be in Chinese) you'll need to know the encoding and convert that byte array to a `String` before printing it. There's a constructor overload for `String(byte[], Charset)`, but as I said -- you'll need to know (or guess) the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the values are stored as `BytesWritable`. That maps to `byte[]` in Java, a byte array -- and that is exactly what's being printed, since the `toString()` method is overloaded to do that.

You also mention that the bytes might be text in Chinese. If you want to output that, you'll need to encode the bytes to `String`. You should change the line

```
bw.write("Value::: " + value);
```

to a couple of others.

```
byte[] strBytes = ((BytesWritable) value).getBytes();
bw.write("Value::: " + new String(strBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

This assumes the Chinese string is encoded using "UTF-8", which might now be the case. You'll have to try different encodings and see what works if you don't know the exact one.

Comment: Yes. It works now. But the output is still garbage. I guess the text should be zipped in some way before written to BytesWritable. Thx.

Comment: As I said, the encoding might be something more locally specific, I know my country uses `Win-1257` on occasion. Chinese might have something equally lame. There are frameworks that can try guessing it, but I can't help you with that.